# Should I extract my functions/types to new files in TypeScript?

Tags: design, object-oriented, object-oriented-design, typescript

Basically I have this class file which was getting quite large with functions and type definitions.

Is it best practice to keep all the code that works on the same aspect in the same file for "Single Responsibility Principle" or should you move parts out to different files, perhaps in a folder with the name of that old class, to make it easier to navigate ?

What are your opinions on this ?
Thank you !

Comment: SRP only applies loosely to a file but it certainly could apply to a module as the latter is a first class API. However, each element of code which is exported should indeed be subject to the principal. So even if you were to export 20 functions from a utilities module (which I do not recommend) it wouldn't necessarily violate SRP as the functions themselves are subject to SRP independently. That's said, I prefer to put almost everything in a separate module, much to the irritation of some colleagues.